Custom in-memory session storage in ASP.NET Core
I would like to maintain my own in-memory session storage in ASP.NET Core. I am planning to use a singleton dictionary and a session key cookie. In case of in-built ASP.NET core session storage, the contents of the session are removed when the session expires. How can I implement similar clean-up for my own in-memory session store?
Note: I do not have any requirement for distributed sessions

would you like to elaborate on why the built-in session features don't suffice for you?

honestly, instead of using a singleton dictionary and writing a lot of code, you should just use redis. you are reinventing the wheel. redis will handle such things like cleanup.

@EmreBener The reason I am unable to use the built-in session feature is because I need to store a complex live (read/write) object in session. ASP.NET core requires serialization and deserialization of session objects and currently that is not an option for us.

@EmreBener How does Redis handle the cleanup? can you share an example or a link?
